# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' with pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, youtube-api

I am trying code from this website: https://datanice.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/sentiment-analysis-for-youtube-channels-with-nltk/

The code I am running into error with is:

```
import nltk
from nltk.probability import *
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd

all = pd.read_csv("comments.csv")

stop_eng = stopwords.words('english')
customstopwords =[]

tokens = []
sentences = []
tokenizedSentences =[]
for txt in all.text:
    sentences.append(txt.lower())
    tokenized = [t.lower().encode('utf-8').strip(":,.!?") for t in txt.split()]
    tokens.extend(tokenized)
    tokenizedSentences.append(tokenized)

hashtags = [w for w in tokens if w.startswith('#')]
ghashtags = [w for w in tokens if w.startswith('+')]
mentions = [w for w in tokens if w.startswith('@')]
links = [w for w in tokens if w.startswith('http') or w.startswith('www')]
filtered_tokens = [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_eng and not w in customstopwords and w.isalpha() and not len(w)<3 and not w in hashtags and not w in ghashtags and not w in links and not w in mentions]

fd = FreqDist(filtered_tokens)
```

This gives me the error of:

```
tokenized = [t.lower().encode('utf-8').strip(":,.!?") for t in txt.split()]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I am getting the csv with this code:

```py
commentDataCsv = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(callFunction).to_csv("comments4.csv", encoding='utf-8')
```

I have replaced all `pd.read_json("comments.csv")` with `read_csv`.

Comment: I assume `"comments4.csv"` and `"comments.csv"` are the same file, just an error of copy and paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Py3, the default string type is unicode.  `encode` converts it to bytestring.  To apply `strip` to bytestring, you need to provide a matching character:

```
In [378]: u'one'.encode('utf-8')                                                     
Out[378]: b'one'
In [379]: 'one'.encode('utf-8').strip(':')                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-379-98728e474af8> in <module>
----> 1 'one'.encode('utf-8').strip(':')

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

In [381]: 'one:'.encode('utf-8').strip(b':')                                         
Out[381]: b'one'
```

If you don't encode first, you can use the default unicode characters

```
In [382]: 'one:'.strip(':')                                                          
Out[382]: 'one'
```

I'd suggest going this route, otherwise the rest of your code will require the `b` token.